# MYSQL 5.5 27 Need to start ID at -200000000 and increment normally +1 per record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a client that wants an MSSQL DB ported over to MYSQL.
the ID's are all negative ints, I need to create some MySQL tables with  Negative INT starting at
-200000000   then incrememt +1 like normal per each new record

Comment: Ok. Go ahead. You have permission. :-) Seriously, you forgot to actually ask a question here, and have no indication that you've tried anything to figure this out yourself.

Comment: MySql supports [Signed Integers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html): [-2147483648, 2147483647]

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, but not signed auto incrementing fields.

Comment: @user:371408 I was just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use auto incrementing fields with negative numbers. From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> The behavior of the auto-increment mechanism is not defined if a user
>   assigns a negative value to the column or if the value becomes bigger
>   than the maximum integer that can be stored in the specified integer
>   type.

I'd suggest just storing your desired ID + 200000000 in MySQL. But presumably you've already thought of that and just want to store the negative number as the ID. Your client will have to generate the ID, and you'll have to make sure the ID generation is safe against concurrency issues. Here's one solution (disclaimer: haven't tested it and it might not be very efficient for many concurrent users):

```
LOCK TABLE MyTable READ; -- Make sure no one else can use the table
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTABLE; -- Find out what the current ID is
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, OtherColumn) VALUES(-100, "x"); -- Derive the ID from the previous value
UNLOCK TABLES; -- Allow others to use table again
```

The `MyTable.ID` column would have to be signed.

Comment: Related post: [mysql setting a negative integer value to a primary auto increment field which is int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554331/mysql-setting-a-negative-integer-value-to-a-primary-auto-increment-field-which-i)

Comment: I manually entered the first record at -20000000, I was then trying this logic Declare X INT;
SET X =(select min(user_id from php_logins);
Select X;      but I keep getting a 1064   any ideas?

Comment: Isn't 1064 a syntax error? Can you show your table definition?